# GNUPLOT multiplot with number

Tags: gnuplot

When I use gnuplot with multiplot, I want to number these plots, but I do not know the way.

I can set the `xlabel` `ylabel` `title` for every plot, but

what is the way to number them as `"1) 2) 3)"` or `"a) b) c)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to put a label on each plot; the command for that is

```
set label "1)" at graph 0.1,0.9
```

gnuplot does not do this automatically.  The coordinates I gave as an example would put the label at the top left.  For more info try `help set label` and `help coord` at the gnuplot command prompt.

EDIT: between plots you will probably want to `unset label` so that you do not get multiple labels in the same spot.

Comment: You should also note that in multiplot you need to disable previous labels with `unset label`, or if you number them e.g. with `set label 1 "(a)" ...` then use `unset label 1` after usage, otherwise the first plot will have one label, the second plot will have two labels, and so on. Also, it's best to set the label using the `screen` coordinate system rather than `graph` so they always appear at the same relative position in the graph.

Comment: @Miguel About the label number you are right, about the coordinates not. `graph` is the right coordinate system for this: See the following example with `screen` and with `graph`: `set multiplot layout 1,2; set label 1 at screen 0.1,0.9 'label'; plot x; plot 2*x; unset multiplot`

Comment: @Christoph True, my bad! I'm used to using margins rather than size+origin with multiplot. In this case you can always refer to the screen coordinates, that got me confused. Apologies!